# OpenCL: Manually throw an exception in kernel

Tags: opencl

Is it possible to manually throw an exception in OpenCL, just for debugging purposes? I am having a very strange error in my code: when I computed two double values and add them up, the   host reports "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCE". However if I don't add these two values, the host doesn't report any error.

Comment: you cannot write exception or try/catch block inside the kernel. CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCE could be because of many reasons, could you post your host and kernel code ? also let me know the hardware configuration you are running, AMD, Intel, NVIDIA?

Comment: @ocluser Thanks for your help, but the code I am working on is based on an algorithm in a paper yet to be published. I cannot make anything public until that paper get published. The problem seems disappeared after I switched to AMD platform (Radeon HD5850) from NVIDIA platform (GTX460M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are not supported in OpenCL - it is based on the C99 language.

On AMD GPUs you can use `printf` inside the kernel - see the `cl_amd_printf` extension. To use, put this at the top of your .cl file:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf : enable
```

Comment: Intel OpenCL SDK supports printf by default, I just found out.

Comment: @Polymorpher That would be only for Intel CPU OpenCL devices. 'printf' is provided by the compiler (through the driver), not through the SDK. It doesn't matter which SDK you are using - it's the device (and driver) that matters.