# Can one induce a user-defined error from an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl

For debugging purposes, I would like to be able to induce an OpenCL error of my choosing from a kernel. My intended use case would be to use this capability like an assertion

```
__kernel void myKernel(...)
{
  ...
  if(i < j){
    InduceOpenCLError(-9999);
  }
  ...
};
```

Is this possible, and if not, is there any other useful way to include an "assertion" which will obviously induce a runtime error if a certain assumption is not true?

This question is related, but slightly different:
[OpenCL: Manually throw an exception in kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245247/opencl-manually-throw-an-exception-in-kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is something missing from OpenCL.  As the question you referenced suggested you do have `printf` to report an error, but even that is kind of clunky and doesn't help you detect an error programmatically.

If you are really set on returning an error codes, I can think of a couple options (none easy).

First, you could pass a buffer to contain all the status values for each work item.  After running the kernel, you'd need host code to go through and check the values.  You could conditionally include this code as shown below just for debugging. (The following being totally untested.)

```
#ifndef RETURN_STATUSES
#define RETURN_STATUS(S) \
  do { \
    _kernel_status[get_global_id(0)] = (S); \
    return; \
  } while (0)
#else
#define RETURN_STATUS(S) return
#endif

kernel void myKernel(
  ... normal args
#ifdef RETURN_STATUSES
  , global int *_kernel_status
#endif
  )
{
  ...
  if (i < j) {
    RETURN_STATUS(-9999);
  }
}
```

Another option might be to atomically set a single value. Again, this has significant performance impact and would be good for debug only.

The lack of an efficient way to indicate error in OpenCL kernels is definitely a sore point for me too.

Comment: I ended up using an even quicker-and-dirtier version of this approach, which is to pass a single global memory location to every kernel, bitwise-and various single-bit integer values, and check the status after my kernel calls. This is not proper error handling, obviously, but is enough to induce an error on assertion failure.